# Upstart Job (.conf) Fails to Install

Tags: dpkg, upstart

I have a simple package (.deb) wherein the main goal is to create an Upstart job. Call it Foo. It fails to create the job file `/etc/init/Foo.conf`.

#### Package Definition

I have created the package source using `dh_make --createorig` and added `Foo.upstart` to the `debian` directory. I build the package with `debuild -us -uc`.

#### Installation

`sudo dpkg -i Foo_1.0-1_all.deb`

When I install the package on one machine it goes fine, but another it fails. (Foo.conf is added to `/etc/init` and the service is started).  **That is, Foo.conf is not added to `/etc/init`.** The backwards-compatibility Foo script (symbolic link to `upstart-job`) does get added to `/etc/init.d`, and doc files are added to `/usr/share/doc/Foo`. But, `/etc/init/Foo.conf` is missing.

#### EDIT

Originally I believed the problem was due to architecture. That was simply because I had a working install on amd64, but the problem occurred on an i386 machine. I neglected to realize that I had previously done manual installation & removal on the i386 machine which dpkg avoided interfering with.

Comment: i've not done this in a long time, but are you doing this? `dpkg --add-architecture i386` ??

Comment: I have not tried that. However, reading the docs it seems that might be for the reverse problem: if I had an i386 package that I wanted to install on an amd64 machine. In my case, I can create an i386 package on the i386 machine. It is a non-binary package so seems like there should be no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Troubleshooting

When a package fails to install you can troubleshoot by using the Debug switch. It takes a bitfield to determine the level and subject-matter. A value of D=7777 will show everything. For this problem we know we are specifically interested in conf files so we can use D=220.

`sudo dpkg -D=220 -i Foo_1.0-1_all.deb`

Your output may show something like the following:

```
D000200: conffderef in='/etc/init/Foo.conf' current working='/etc/init/Foo.conf'
D000200: conffderef nonexistent
D000020: deferred_configure '/etc/init/Foo.conf' (= '/etc/init/Foo.conf') useredited=1 distedited=0 what=2002
```

The key clue is **`useredited=1`**. By default `dpkg` will not replace user-edited configuration files. Manually deleting a .conf file counts as editing it, so it may come as a surprise that dpkg will not replace the missing file. It may be doubly-surprising for those experienced with installing services on other operating systems that an Upstart Job is treated as configuration.

### Force missing conf installation

dpkg has a handful of force options. You can force the replacement of the missing .conf file as so:

`sudo dpkg -i --force-confmiss Foo_1.0-1_all.deb`

There are other force options for similar scenarios; check the manual page or use `dpkg --force-help` for details. These options should be used with care, especially for 3rd party packages.

### Package Dev/Test Cycle

In the development of a .deb package (e.g. for an Upstart Job) you'll be installing and removing the package many times. You'll also possibly be tweaking the .conf file manually at times. By default `dpkg -r` (or `apt-get remove`) will not remove the .conf file. (So surprisingly the upstart job remains while associated binaries may be gone.) For this you must use the purge option. Therefore to test completely removing and reinstalling the upstart job, you can do the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i Foo_1.0-1_all.deb
# testing...
sudo apt-get purge Foo
```

And now that you know about the force and debug options you can apply those as needed.

### References

See the thread [Bug#1198: dpkg silently fails to install a file](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/1995/08/msg00091.html):

> Removing the file counts as `editing' it, because for many
>   configuration files the absence of a file is meaningful.

[Manual page for `dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)